# How to perform AND condition in django queryset?

Tags: python, python-2.7, django-models

I want to write a Django query equivalent to this SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE name LIKE '%danny%' AND name LIKE '%jack%' AND name LIKE '%peter%' ...
```

In `Django` , i have a list for example :

```
lst=['danny','jack','peter']
```

How to construct the `Djagno queryset` filter?

Comment: You can chain `.filter(name__contains="danny").filter(name__contains="jack").filter(name__contains="peter")`

Comment: I don't know your solution is correct, becuse my list is input pramater@NightShadeQueen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Q operator:

```
queryargs = [Q(name__contains=i) for i in lst]
queryset = User.objects.filter(*queryargs)
```

**UPDATE**

I have answered the question, but given your second, expanded question on how to obtain the combination

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE (name LIKE '%danny%' AND name LIKE '%jack%' AND name LIKE '%peter%') OR (family LIKE '%danny%' AND family LIKE '%jack%' AND family LIKE '%peter%')
```

this should work:

```
from django.db.models import Q

qname = Q()
for i in lst:
    qname &= Q(name__contains=i)

qfamily = Q()
for i in lst:
    qfamily &= Q(family__contains=i)

queryset = Data.objects.filter(qname | qfamily)
```

Comment: Tnx a lot @Pynchia
now,how to construct the `Djagno queryset filter` this query ? 

`SELECT * FROM user WHERE (name LIKE '%danny%' AND name LIKE '%jack%' AND name LIKE '%peter%') OR (family LIKE '%danny%' AND family LIKE '%jack%' AND family LIKE '%peter%')`